# PostgreSQL, сравнение SETOF внутри одной таблицы

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имею две функции в Postgres:

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION transposed_values_sum(matrix_id integer) RETURNS setof int AS
$$
    SELECT RowID+ColumnID+CellValue as cellvalue from transpose(matrix_id)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE OR replace FUNCTION values_sum(matrix_id integer) RETURNS setof int  AS
$$
    SELECT RowID+ColumnID+CellValue as cellvalue from find_matrix(matrix_id)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;
```

В третьей функции необходимо сравнить то, что они вернули.
Грубо говоря, хотел оформить в следующем виде, но DataGrip выдает ошибку:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION is_symmetric(matrix_id integer) RETURNS bool_answer AS
$BODY$
declare
  MyDesiredResult varchar;
BEGIN
  FOR I IN transposed_values_sum(matrix_id) LOOP
    IF transposed_values_sum(matrix_id)[I] = values_sum(matrix_id)[I]
    THEN MyDesiredResult = 'YES';
    ELSE MyDesiredResult = 'NO';
    END IF;
  return MyDesiredResult;
    END LOOP ;
END;
$BODY$ LANGUAGE plpgsql volatile;
```

Нет ли верной и более эффективной методики это сделать?
Если надо, то можно и поменять тип возвращаемых значений первых двух функций.

Comment: full outer join? inner join?

Comment: on what? Не совсем понятно как это поможет определить равенство множеств.

Comment: Джойните между собой два вызова функций по нужному критерию. К булеву ответу можете прийти обернув полученный запрос в exists.